# Two screens with the same dimensions but different resolutions in Web

Tags: css, web, screen-resolution

I am trying to create the responsive header and I applied the style as follows,

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
 .headerText {
    left: 40%;
 }
}
```

When I am testing the same in two machine with same resolution (1366*768) with different monitor size 15" and 19" , It shows the different view.

So is there any way that, I can apply different css for different size monitor or what would be the best solution for this?

Note: There is same question in the community but that is focused on the anriod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have added viewport in head section.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Basically Viewport is worked when rendering responsive pages and is therefore mostly used when dealing with mobile websites, but when dealing with media queries it helps tell the CSS what the actual device-width is.

Comment: Please try this
@media screen 
 and (max-device-width: 1400px) 
 and (min-device-width: 1300px) 
{ }